# vba - PasteSpecial - Method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have been following this video on youtube [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIqoXYy_Clg&lc=Ugzu2-4h-3DoJgSTyF94AaABAg.9CsobxkPWqH9CttCQ3Auph) and I have copied the code that the author of the video shows.

However, when I try to replicate it, I get the following error '***Method or data member not found***' and the highlighted segment of the code is '***.PasteSpecial***'.

Can anyone help me understand why?
I am using the exact same code and input data of the author of the video.
Don't know if it is relevant, but I am running Excel 2016 on a Mac. The following references are activated:

- Visual Basics for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
- Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library

```
Option Explicit

'app
'  pre
'   slide
'    shapes
'     text frame
'      text

Sub ExporttoPPT()

'-----------------------------
'Thanks for downloading the code.
'Please visit our channel for a quick explainer on this code.
'Feel free to update the code as per your need and also share with your friends.
'Download free codes from http://vbaa2z.blogspot.com
'Subscribe channel: youtube.com/vbaa2z
'Author: L Pamai (vbaa2z.team@gmail.com)
'-----------------------------

Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slde As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range

Dim vSheet$
Dim vRange$
Dim vWidth As Double
Dim vHeight As Double
Dim vTop As Double
Dim vLeft As Double
Dim vSlide_No As Long
Dim expRng As Range

Dim adminSh As Worksheet
Dim cofigRng As Range
Dim xlfile$
Dim pptfile$


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set adminSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
Set cofigRng = adminSh.Range("Rng_sheets")

xlfile = adminSh.[excelPth]
pptfile = adminSh.[pptPth]
      
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)


For Each rng In cofigRng
   
   '----------------- set VARIABLES
   With adminSh
      vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value
      vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 5).Value
      vWidth = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
      vHeight = .Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
      vTop = .Cells(rng.Row, 8).Value
      vLeft = .Cells(rng.Row, 9).Value
      vSlide_No = .Cells(rng.Row, 10).Value
   End With
   
   
   '----------------- EXPORT TO PPT
   
            wb.Activate
            Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
            Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
            expRng.Copy
            
            Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)
            slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteBitmap
            Set shp = slde.Shapes(1)
            
            With shp
               
               .Top = vTop
               .Left = vLeft
               .Width = vWidth
               .Height = vHeight
               
            End With
            
            
            Set shp = Nothing
            Set slde = Nothing
            Set expRng = Nothing
   
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Set expRng = Nothing
Next rng

pre.Save
pre.Close

Set pre = Nothing
Set ppt_app = Nothing

wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**Update**

Based on some comments below, the issue might be that the command PasteSpecial is not present in Mac. For instance, when I replace

```
slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteBitmap
```

with

```
slde.Shapes.Paste DataType:=ppPasteBitmap
```

or

```
slde.Shapes.Paste
```

The code seems to run but then Excel crashes. So I still need some help :)

Comment: @Davesexcel No it is not. The code works for the author, I assume it has something to do with my machine instead of with the code?

Comment: Your right, the question was not resolved. I hate when something works for one person but not for another.

Comment: PasteSpecial differs between Mac and Windows. I suggest that you find out what works by recording a macro where you use *paste special* in Excel or Word.

Comment: I haven't watched all of the video (actually i only saw the first 29 seconds of the video :)). Whats apparent is that the video is based on Windows OS. From what I understand, there are difference in Excel Windows and Excel Mac (although I've never worked on Excel Mac so cannot confirm). I suspect that's where your issue is

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.exceltip.com/excel-keyboard-shortcuts/paste-special-shortcut-in-mac-and-windows.html) might help?

Comment: Thank you @Zac and Sam. I think you are right. For instance, when I change 'PasteSpecial' to 'Paste', the code runs but after a few seconds Excel crashes. So I guess I need to fix this new problem now :-)

Comment: PowerPoint for Mac VBA has an incomplete object model. It's all too common find code that will run in Windows but not on the Mac